# void class Arrays Sequential and Binary Search Using

Tags: c++, search, binary, sequential

I'm currently at my wits end trying to figure out how to do this, and was hoping someone could help.

The objectives the assignment is to:

1. Display the original sorted array of student records.
2. Display the sequential search result of student records.
3. Display the binary search result of student records.

The Full Instructions are:

a. Create three array of 12+ students records including ID’s, student names, and

the corresponding e-mail address’,– student ID’s are sorted in order. (No sort program needed for now.)

b. Sequential Search five ID’s which are from the sorted array and a 6th ID which is not from the array.

c. Binary Search five ID’s which are from the sorted array and a 6th ID which is not from the array.

d. Execution and output:

1. Display the original sorted array of student records.
2. Display the sequential search result of student records.
3. Display the binary search result of student records.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    int stuID;
    string email;
};


// Show the student information
void showAllInfo(Student *studentArray, int stuCount) {
    cout << "Student Info: "<<endl <<endl<<
        "\t\tStudent Name"<<"\t\tStudent ID"<<"\t\tStudent Email"<<endl<<endl ;

    for (int i = 0; i < stuCount; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\t\t"<< studentArray[i].name<<"\t\t"<<studentArray[i].stuID<<"\t\t\t"<< studentArray[i].email<<endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


}


//Sort out the arrays for the student information
void firstArray()
{

    Student studentArray[12];

    studentArray[0].name = "Bob McBoberston";
    studentArray[0].stuID = 00;
    studentArray[0].email = "BMcboberts@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[1].name = "Shelby Donald";
        studentArray[1].stuID = 1;
        studentArray[1].email = "SDonald@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[2].name = "Ronald Mcdonald";
        studentArray[2].stuID = 2;
        studentArray[2].email = "RMcdonald@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[3].name = "Dick Cheney";
        studentArray[3].stuID = 3;
        studentArray[3].email = "DCheney@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[4].name= "Ben Dover";
        studentArray[4].stuID=4;
        studentArray[4].email="BDover@txstate.edu"; 

        studentArray[5].name="Ash Katchum";
        studentArray[5].stuID=5;
        studentArray[5].email="AKatchum@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[6].name="Brock Whatever";
        studentArray[6].stuID=6;
        studentArray[6].email="BWhatevr@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[7].name="Yugi Oh";
        studentArray[7].stuID=7;
        studentArray[7].email="YugiOh@txstate.edu";         

        studentArray[8].name="Johnny Bravo";
        studentArray[8].stuID=8;
        studentArray[8].email="JBravo@txstate.edu";


        studentArray[9].name="Tom N. Jerry";
        studentArray[9].stuID=9;
        studentArray[9].email="Tnjerry@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[10].name="Fred Flinstone";
        studentArray[10].stuID=10;
        studentArray[10].email="FFlinstone@emial.com";

        studentArray[11].name="Son Goku";
        studentArray[11].stuID=11;
        studentArray[11].email="sGoku@txstate.edu";

        studentArray[12].name="Johnny Test";
        studentArray[12].stuID=12;
        studentArray[12].email="JTest@txstate.edu";
    }

void secondArray()
{
    Student studentArray2[12];

    studentArray2[0].name = "Rick Sanchez";
    studentArray2[0].stuID = 13;
    studentArray2[0].email = "RSanchez@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[1].name="Morty Smith";
        studentArray2[1].stuID = 14;
        studentArray2[1].email = "MSmith@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[2].name = "Summer Smith";
        studentArray2[2].stuID = 15;
        studentArray2[2].email = "SSmith@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[3].name = "Jerry Smith";
        studentArray2[3].stuID = 16;
        studentArray2[3].email = "JSmith@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[4].name="Mr. Meeseeks";
        studentArray2[4].stuID=17;
        studentArray2[4].email="MMeeseeks@txstate.edu"; 

        studentArray2[5].name="Mr. PoopyButtHole";
        studentArray2[5].stuID=18;
        studentArray2[5].email="MPoopyButt@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[6].name="Tiny Rick";
        studentArray2[6].stuID=19;
        studentArray2[6].email="TRick@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[7].name="Pickle Rick";
        studentArray2[7].stuID=20;
        studentArray2[7].email="PRick@txstate.edu";     

        studentArray2[8].name="Beth Smith";
        studentArray2[8].stuID=21;
        studentArray2[8].email="BSmith@txstate.edu";


        studentArray2[9].name="Bird Person";
        studentArray2[9].stuID=22;
        studentArray2[9].email="BmPerson@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[10].name="Squanchy";
        studentArray2[10].stuID=23;
        studentArray2[10].email="Squanchy@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[11].name="King Flippy Nips";
        studentArray2[11].stuID=24;
        studentArray2[11].email="KFlippyNipa@txstate.edu";

        studentArray2[12].name="Mr> Goldenfold";
        studentArray2[12].stuID=25;
        studentArray2[12].email="MGoldenfold@txstate.edu";
    }

void thirdArray()
{

Student studentArray3[13];

    studentArray3[0].name = "Santa Claus";
    studentArray3[0].stuID = 26;
    studentArray3[0].email = "SClause@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[1].name = "Jason Riha";
        studentArray3[1].stuID = 27;
        studentArray3[1].email = "JRiha@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[2].name = "B-Rad Cragg";
        studentArray3[2].stuID = 28;
        studentArray3[2].email = "BRad@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[3].name="Roger Legrand";
        studentArray3[3].stuID = 29;
        studentArray3[3].email = "RLegrand@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[4].name="David De La O";
        studentArray3[4].stuID=30;
        studentArray3[4].email= "DDelao@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[5].name="Ian Sporn";
        studentArray3[5].stuID=31;
        studentArray3[5].email="ISporn@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[6].name="Morgan Taylor";
        studentArray3[6].stuID=32;
        studentArray3[6].email="Mytaylor@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[7].name="Sam Huggins";
        studentArray3[7].stuID=33;
        studentArray3[7].email="SHuggins@txstate.edu";      

        studentArray3[8].name="Shaun Huggins";
        studentArray3[8].stuID=34;
        studentArray3[8].email="ShuHuggins@txstate.edu";


        studentArray3[9].name="Serena Huggins";
        studentArray3[9].stuID=35;
        studentArray3[9].email="SerHuggins@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[10].name="Kylie Parziale";
        studentArray3[10].stuID=36;
        studentArray3[10].email="KParziale@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[11].name="Jimmy Fallon";
        studentArray3[11].stuID=37;
        studentArray3[11].email="JFallon@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[12].name="Tom Goat Brady";
        studentArray3[12].stuID=38;
        studentArray3[12].email="TGBrady@txstate.edu";

        studentArray3[13].name="Harry Giblets";
        studentArray3[13].stuID=39;
        studentArray3[13].email="HGiblets@txstate.edu";
    }


int main() {

    int stuCount = 39;
firstArray();
secondArray();
thirdArray();   

showAllInfo(studentArray,stuCount);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For working code, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate. if it is not working, state which part doesn't work (input, expected output, current output) and try to reduce your example to minimal.

Comment: A variable declared inside a function only exists within that function. There is no `studentArray` in `main`, it only exists in the context of the functions that declare it.

Comment: The three array requirement is a little confusing, as the rest of the requirments just say 'the array'. I would clarify that with the teacher before you go any further.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few problems. The first is that your arrays are declared inside the functions you've written, so no other code is going to be able to access them. You should declare your arrays inside the `main` function so that they can be *passed as parameters* to other functions. If you don't know how to pass an array as a parameter then the rest of this assignment is going to be difficult for you.

Anyway lets start like this, you don't need to write function to set up your arrays, you can do it directly in main, like this

```
int main()
{
    Student firstArray[12] = {
        { "Bob McBoberston", 0, "BMcboberts@txstate.edu" },
        ...
    };
    Student secondArray[12] = {
        ...
    };
    Student thirdArray[12] = {
        ...
    };

    ...
}
```

Now that the arrays are set up you need to write a function to do the sequential search (binary search is more complex, so leave that one for now).

Think about what *parameters* a function needs and what *return* value it has. This is *always* the first step when writing a function, but it's also one that many newbies struggle with.

In the case a sequential search function it needs to know 1) which array is it going to search, 2) how big that array is, 3) what id you are searching for. These are the parameters. It seems reasonable for the function to return the index in the array of the person it's found, or a special value `-1` if it doesn't find the id. That's not the only way to do it, but it'll do for now. So putting that together we have

```
// look for 'id' in 'array' and returns the index if found or -1 if not found
int sequential_search(Person array[], int array_size, int id)
{
    ...
}
```

In your main function you would use this function something like this

```
int main()
{
    ...
    // look for person with id 5
    int id = 5;
    int index = sequential_search(firstArray, 12, id);
    if (index == -1)
         cout << "ID " << id << " not found\n";
    else
         cout << "ID " << id << " is " << firstArray[index].name << "\n";
}
```

Get the idea? Hopefully this gives you a start. You can do the rest, and ask again if you get into difficulties.